# Why doesn't this MySQL query from Google example work? (haversine formula)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a scenario where I want to find all the rows in a table that are within certain radius to a given coordinate of latitude and longitude.

This is the structure of the table:

```
id | name | address | lat | lng
-------------------------------
```

So for example, I am given a coordinate: latitude and longitude and I need to find all the rows that are 25 miles away from the given coordinate.

I found this Google tutorial on how to do just that: [Creating a Store Locator on Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator)

But no matter what I try to do, I always get 0 results. This is the PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(-33) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(151) ) + sin( radians(-33) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$number_of_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

echo $number_of_rows; // echoes 0
```

My table has the exact same columns and rows as in the Google store locator:

```
1,Heir Apparel,"Crowea Pl, Frenchs Forest NSW 2086",-33.737885,151.235260
2,BeeYourself Clothing,"Thalia St, Hassall Grove NSW 2761",-33.729752,150.836090
3,Dress Code,"Glenview Avenue, Revesby, NSW 2212",-33.949448,151.008591
4,The Legacy,"Charlotte Ln, Chatswood NSW 2067",-33.796669,151.183609
5,Fashiontasia,"Braidwood Dr, Prestons NSW 2170",-33.944489,150.854706
6,Trish & Tash,"Lincoln St, Lane Cove West NSW 2066",-33.812222,151.143707
7,Perfect Fit,"Darley Rd, Randwick NSW 2031",-33.903557,151.237732
8,Buena Ropa!,"Brodie St, Rydalmere NSW 2116",-33.815521php,151.026642
9,Coxcomb and Lily Boutique,"Ferrers Rd, Horsley Park NSW 2175",-33.829525,150.873764
10,Moda Couture,"Northcote Rd, Glebe NSW 2037",-33.873882,151.177460
```

Comment: Are your sure that any of your points actually is within your chosen distance? Maybe try increasing 25 to something bigger.

Comment: Oh god, since all coordinates started with -33 and 151 I was sure they are within 25 miles. I increased to 200 and it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not the same as in the Google link. Try to change it to:

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM markers 
HAVING distance < 25 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

As you can see, in your query you have in the beginning `cos( radians(-33) )` and Google query has `cos( radians(37) )` and some other differences

**EDIT**

Maybe you are right and the data is not correct in the example, and even with your data, all distances are greater than 50. Try with this one:

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(-34) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(151) ) + sin( radians(-34) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM markers 
having distance<25
 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Or change in yours and set `HAVING<60`

Comment: Yes but I think 37 and -122 means that the latitude is 37 and longitude is -122 so in the Google tutorial they have a mistake, because the coordinates in the table are -33 and 151. By the way I already tried with 37 and -122 but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

just rename column name as per your table and try

```
$sql = "
SELECT id
     , ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(-33) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(151) ) + sin( radians(-33) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
  FROM places 
 HAVING distance < 25 
 ORDER 
  BY distance 
 LIMIT 0 , 20;
";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$number_of_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

echo $number_of_rows; // echoes 0
```

Comment: SORRY, the wrong column names came from another PHP script I wrote, but the non-working script has exactly the one you wrote and still not working. I edited the post, thank you